# Combine two files column-wise in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-editing

I have two files: one is like

```
preface
Introduction
chapter 1
```

the other is like

```
1
2
3
```

I was wondering how to  column-wise combine the two files into one:

```
preface 1
Introduction 2
chapter 1 3
```

by using some utilities, such as awk, sed, available in Ubuntu?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: For such file manipulation I would look for the join command. It requires a common field though, but you could add one like line number, no ?

Comment: @Julien: How do you do with join?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
paste fileone filetwo
```

Use `-d` to specify delimiter.

Comment: Thanks! I just found that `pr -t -m firstfile secondfile` can also do the similar job. Are there differences between the two methods?